# How can I enforce a maximum number of connections from one user with Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, spam-prevention, rate-limiting

I have a very simple Socket.IO group chat system ([this one](http://quibbler.co)). I want to prevent people from spamming new connections from their browser using JavaScript trickery. This was a problem the one time I publicized the website.

What measure should I use to prevent this? I want to count the number of connections from a browser and it it goes over a threshold, I want to drop all connections. Should I use the IP address? Is the `socket.id` unique to a user? How should I do it?

If you want to look at the Socket.IO code, see the [highlighted code here](https://github.com/Antrikshy/Quibbler/blob/master/app.js#L52-L108).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in a multiplayer game, to prevent a user playing through more than one tabs.

There's so many ways a client can refuse to be identified, and having their way of logging in with more than one ID. But since you only want to prevent a user in the same browser it's relatively easy.

First, use [passport](http://passportjs.org/) for authentication and [passport.socketio](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) to "bridge" `req.user` from Express middleware to `socket.request.user`

Next, since `io.on('connection')` will always fire for the latest socket request from the client, you can use this as an opportunity to "expire" any old sockets still connected from the same client. This is where `socket.request.user` will come in handy to identify whether it's the same user client. Something like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var user = socket.request.user;

    // Suppose this user has connected from another tab,
    // then the socket.id from current tab will be
    // different from [see *1]

    var current_socket_id = socket.id;
    var last_socket_id = user.latest_socket_id;

    if (last_socket_id) {
        // If the user has an existing socket connection
        // from the previously opened tab,

        // Send disconnection request to the previous socket
        io.to(last_socket_id).emit('disconnect');
        // client-side will look like
        // socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        //     alert('You connected from a new tab, this tab will close now.')
        //     window.close();
        // });
    }

    // [*1] current socket.id is stored in the user
    user.latest_socket_id = socket.id;
    user.save();
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this group chat is not authenticated.

Comment: You can pseudo-authenticate with randomly generated credentials without user input.